# How should my matrix (multiplication) equation look like?

Tags: matrices, hadamard-product

Consider the following matrix:
\begin{align}
X=\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11}\;\; x_{12} \\
x_{21}\;\; x_{22} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
I want to multiply each element by $e_{ij}$, so I finally have the following matrix:
\begin{align}
EX=\begin{bmatrix}
e_{11}x_{11}\;\; e_{12}x_{12} \\
e_{21}x_{21}\;\; e_{22}x_{22} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
But what should I multiply $X$ with to obtain $EX$?

Comment: This doesn't look like matrix multiplication to me.  In what context does this problem arise?

Comment: Assume that I want to multiply production value by country $i$ and sector $j$, $X$, by an emission intensity by country $i$ and sector $j$, $E$. How do I write that equation as an matrix equation. It is easy if the emission intensity only was by country $i$, because then it could have been a diagonal matrix. But I am not sure when it is by country and sector. Does it make sense? :-)

Comment: What you are describing is a [hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)).  This is not accomplished with usual matrix multiplication.

Comment: Ah, perfectly! Thanks a lot! :-)